# How do I edit conky templates to dynamically show attached USB devices?

Tags: bash, templates, awk, sed, conky

I have followed the example from [Casey's Conky Reference with Examples](http://www.ifxgroup.net/conky.htm#execgraph)
.

I modified it to have

```
[conky config section]
 -- Format the storage information the same way for every device. Parameters: [human name] [path]
template3 = "\\1 [${fs_size \\2} ${fs_type \\2}]${alignr}${fs_used \\2} used ${fs_bar 10,60 \\2}\n${alignr}${voffset -15}${fs_used_perc \\2}%\nMount=${color3}\\2$color",

[conky TEXT section]
${execpi 60 df -h -t ext4 -t vfat -t fuse.sshfs -t fuseblk -t hfsplus --output=source,target | grep  -ve "boot" -ve "nvme0"  -ve "sda"  | grep '^/dev/' | cut --characters=6- | sed 's/^/\$\{template3 /;s/$/\}/'}
```

which is working.

I would like to separate out the name of the USB device and display it, instead of displaying the entire path of the mount point.

So, I have tried the lines below:

```
[conky config section]
template3 = "\\1 [${fs_size \\2} ${fs_type \\2}]${alignr}${fs_used \\2} used ${fs_bar 10,60 \\2}\n${alignr}${voffset -15}${fs_used_perc \\2}%\nName=${color3}\\$color",

[conky TEXT section]
${execpi 60 df -h -t ext4 -t vfat -t fuse.sshfs -t fuseblk -t hfsplus --output=source,target | grep  -ve "boot" -ve "nvme0"  -ve "sda"  | grep '^/dev/' | awk -F/ '{printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, $NF}' | cut --characters=6- | sed 's/^/\$\$\{template3 /;s/$/$/\}/'}
```

I don't know how to get that to work, maybe because I am not very good with `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a 3rd argument to the template, and refer to it with `\\3`. So you change it to:

```
template3 = "...Name=${color3}\\3$color"
```

This 3rd argument must be separated by spaces when the template is actually used, not by the tab `\t` you have used in the added `awk`. You didn't need to change the sed, which just surrounds the output with `${template3 ... }`.

Instead of mixing grep, awk, and sed, you can do it all in awk more easily. Try:

```
${execpi 60 df -h -t ext4 -t vfat -t fuse.sshfs -t fuseblk \
  -t hfsplus --output=source,target |
 awk -F/ '/boot|nvme0|sda/{ next }
          $0 ~ "^/dev/" { printf "${template3 %s %s}\n",substr($0,6),$NF }'}
```

The original `grep -ve "boot"` means match lines *not* containing "boot". The awk equivalent would be `/boot/{ next }`, that is: if you match the regular expression "boot" in the input line, just go on to handle the next input line instead. The regular expression `/boot|nvme0|sda/` means `boot` or `nvme0` or `sda`.

The original `grep '^/dev/'` uses a regular expression which means only match lines beginning (`^`) with `/dev/`.  The awk equivalent can be `/^\/dev\//{print}`, but since regular expressions must be in `//` this means you need to escape the `/` and can be a bit less readable than the alternative:
`$0 ~ "^/dev/" {....}`, where `$0` is the whole line, `~` means match, and you can use a string in quotes as a regular expression.

The original `cut ...` means from the 6th character, and awk has a function `substr(string, start, length)` to make a sub-string that can do that. If no length is given, the whole of the rest of the string is returned.

You are allowed newlines in `${exec}` forms, but you must be careful with templates: use an artifice to ensure `${template3` never occurs in the string. Here I used `$\{`.

Comment: Some explanation of the `awk` would be beneficial.

Comment: I added some explanations, and replaced the `if()` in the awk by the same thing as a line selector.

Comment: The `awk` is a lot easier to understand. No need to study `sed` I think.

Comment: The slashes around `template` are required for `conky`. The terminal claims they are unnecessary (when you test the bash command inside the `${execi.. }` statement).

Comment: I have a fairly old version of conky, 1.10.4, and I had to experiment to see what managed to get through `$execp`, as there was not too much documentation on what should happen. Perhaps your version is better at parsing this. I will have to see if I can get a newer version, thanks.